# Why my dependency is not found in pom.xml file?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

[Image][1]I wanted to import my PostgreSQL dependency in pom.xml file to connect it to spring boot, but I am getting this message Dependency 'org.postgresql:postgresql:Runtime' not found . My Intellij Idea is community version.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRoJy.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>youtubeSpringBoot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>youtubeSpringBoot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>Runtime</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>olg.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: if it's possible, can you post your pom xml in here?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Ok.

Comment: Use "42.2.14" instead of Runtime in the "Version" node of PostgreSQL. See https://i.imgur.com/OdYAPSv.png

Comment: I tried, but it didn't help. Also, I couln't add Maven dependency. Maybe this is causing this problem.

Comment: Dependency 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.14' not found  the same message

Comment: The version is not `Runtime` (you probably meant `<scope>runtime</scope>`, and that's case-sensitive). You should also try without specifying any version at all; Spring Boot manages most versions for you.

Answer (score 3):

Please try using following and change version from following link
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.2.23</version>
</dependency>
```

In your POM version been defined "RUNTIME", while scope could be runtime not version.

Comment: I included the version, but it is still not recognizing.

Answer (score 0):

please try using scope and change something like that:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally, it worked.I turns out it is because of the version of intellij Idea. When I run this program on ultimate version, I didn't face this issue.

Comment: this doesn't make any sense. Always use maven CLI when IDE is in doubt

Comment: I got it. I have to import those dependency manually by downloding it. Am I right?Because when I did so, it worked.

Comment: that's not correct. Maven manages dependencies. What you downloaded and where? I'm sure there is no version called `Runtime` as you stated in question

Comment: Yeah, You are right. I am so confused by the mave dependencies because I am new to Spring boot.